# How to encrypt JDBC password for apache-tomcat-9.0.74?

Tags: security, tomcat, jdbc

Decryption of JDBC Password for Tomcat not working for apache-tomcat-9.0.74 using SecureTomcatJDBC.jar. What should be the work around?

I followed the steps provided in https://www.aivhub.com/wiki/aiv_secureJDBCpassword.html.
I generated the encrypted password using the command "java -jar SecureTomcatJDBC.jar password".
Then I placed the SecureTomcatJDBC.jar in the lib of Tomcat.

```
<Resource name="jdbc/PegaRULES"
          auth="Container"
          type="javax.sql.DataSource"
          factory="SecureTomcatDataSourceImpl"
          driverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver"
          url="jdbc:postgresql://db1.rds.amazonaws.com:5432/dbdev"
          username="pegaadmin"
          password="b67720a6c39db763b7f"
          maxActive="100"
          maxIdle="30"
          maxWait="60000"
          connectionProperties=""
          validationQuery="SELECT 1"
          validationInterval="30000"
          testWhileIdle="true"
          timeBetweenEvictionRunsMills="10000"
          />
```

The decryption of password is working for apache-tomcat-9.0.73, but the same is not working apache-tomcat-9.0.74.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is not due to the versions of JDK and Tomcat.
It was found that the actual password of pegaadmin started with $ character. So the password of pegaadmin was changed by the DBA and the new password now starts with c.
This password was encrypted by the command "java -jar SecureTomcatJDBC.jar c*******" and the new encrypted password was put into the context.xml file.

With the new password the decryption by Tomcat was successful and the issue is resolved.

So, this is a bug of the SecureTomcatJDBC.jar file.